# Get current value selected in dropdown using jQuery

Tags: jquery

I have a set of dynamically generated dropdown boxes on my page. basically I clone them using jQuery. now I want to capture the value selected on each dropdown on change event.

I tried something like this which did not work.

```
$('._someDropDown').live('change', function(e) {
            //debugger;
            var v = $(this);
            alert($(this + ':selected').val());
            alert($(this).val());
        });
```

How do I get it done?

Comment: `$(this).val()` should work. What are you getting from the second alert?

Comment: Hey sorry guys.. its my mistake i m not setting the value of the options....! $(this).val() works fine..

Answer (score 70, accepted):

This is what you need :)

```
$('._someDropDown').live('change', function(e) {
    console.log(e.target.options[e.target.selectedIndex].text);
});
```

For new jQuery use `on`

```
$(document).on('change', '._someDropDown', function(e) {
    console.log(this.options[e.target.selectedIndex].text);
});
```

Comment: @Amit This is pure JavaScript, there may be some jQuery thing for it but I assume this method will be slightly quicker and you can see what is going on if you need to debug anything.

Comment: thanks a lot, this is the solition for my problem ;)

Comment: @Olical Your code works fine in IE 8 also. Thanks :) +1

Comment: Needed this for a different implementation, but works perfect. I figured there would be a way to reference the event but wasn't sure how.

Answer (score 113):

To get the text of the selected option

```
$("#your_select :selected").text();
```

To get the value of the selected option

```
$("#your_select").val();
```

Comment: Perfect answer - comparison between selected value versus selected displayed text.  Thanks!

Comment: Beware - IE8 doesn't support the :selected pseudo-class selector, so you may get a null value in that browser. If you need to support IE8 you may need something like: jQuery(jQuery('#selme option')[jQuery('#selme')[0].selectedIndex]).text()

Answer (score 17):

```
$("#citiesList").change(function() {
    alert($("#citiesList option:selected").text());
    alert($("#citiesList option:selected").val());              
});
```

citiesList is id of select tag

Comment: This is best answer.  Easiest and simple.

Comment: This was the answer that worked for me with Chrome. Thank you.

Answer (score 5):

**Check it Out-->**

**For getting text**

```
$("#selme").change(function(){
 $(this[this.selectedIndex]).text();
});
```

**For getting value**

```
$("#selme").change(function(){
 $(this[this.selectedIndex]).val();
});
```

Answer (score 4):

You can try:

```
$("._someDropDown").val();
```

Comment: This will grab the value of the *first* dropdown, not the one that just changed.

Answer (score 4):

To get the value of a drop-down (select) element, just use val().

```
$('._someDropDown').live('change', function(e) {
  alert($(this).val());
});
```

If you want to the text of the selected option, using this:

```
$('._someDropDown').live('change', function(e) {
  alert($('[value=' + $(this).val() + ']', this).text());
});
```

Answer (score 3):

try this...

```
$("#yourdropdownid option:selected").val();
```

Answer (score 3):

This is actually more efficient and has better readability in my opinion if you want to access your select with *this* or another variable

```
$('#select').find('option:selected')
```

In fact if I remember correctly phpStorm will attempt to auto correct the other method.

Answer (score 3):

In case you want the index of the current selected value.

```
$selIndex = $("select#myselectid").prop('selectedIndex'));
```

Answer (score 1):

The options discussed above won't work because they are not part of the `CSS` specification (it is  `jQuery` extension). Having spent 2-3 days digging around for information, I found that the only way to select the Text of the selected option from the drop down is:

```
{ $("select", id:"Some_ID").find("option[selected='selected']")}
```

Refer to additional notes below:
Because :selected is a `jQuery` extension and not part of the `CSS` specification, queries using :selected cannot take advantage of the performance boost provided by the native DOM querySelectorAll() method. To achieve the best performance when using :selected to select elements, first select the elements using a pure `CSS` selector, then use `.filter(":selected")`. (copied from: http://api.jquery.com/selected-selector/)

Comment: this returns the defaultly selected on load, not the current on change

Answer (score 1):

You can also use `:checked`

```
$("#myselect option:checked").val(); //to get value
```

or as said in other answers simply

```
$("#myselect").val(); //to get value
```

and

```
$("#myselect option:checked").text(); //to get text
```